# mmap() size_t overflow for file ./build/vsarm_firmware.bin

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32

So, I'm trying to create a coding environment for embedded programming (Nucleo-F401RE with on-the-board debug circuit ST-LINK) in VSCode, and one of the things I need to do is obviously flash the code to MCU.
I've been following some tutorial I found online on how to do this and I've mostly been able to patch things that weren't working, but when it comes to flashing the code, I'm pretty much stuck, since I don't really have the adequate knowledge of what's going on here. So, I'm using a tasks.json script with the following task:

```
 {
        "label": "Load Firmware",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "st-flash write ./build/vsarm_firmware.bin 0x08000000",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

And when I try to flash my code to the MCU, I get the following error:

> st-flash 1.6.1
> 2020-07-14T19:03:31 INFO common.c: F4xx (Dynamic Efficency): 96 KiB SRAM, 512 KiB flash in at least 16 KiB pages.
> mmap() size_t overflow for file ./build/vsarm_firmware.bin
> 2020-07-14T19:03:31 ERROR common.c: map_file() == -1
> stlink_fwrite_flash() == -1
> The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command st-flash write ./build/vsarm_firmware.bin 0x08000000" terminated with exit code: 1.

I would really like to tell you what I've tried to fix this, but the reality is that I have no idea where to start here, so I would really like some help here.

Comment: Contact upstream and let them know. The message is from [stlink common.c](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink/blob/develop/src/common.c#L1628). What is the size of `./build/vsarm_firmware.bin` file? Is it over 4 gigabytes?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's 5 KB

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question, only about other software bugs or usage. Just report the bug (issue) to the program author. We cant help you.

Comment: @p__j__ well the thing is: I don't know if it's a programming question or a bug that needs to be reported, maybe I've messed something up on my part?

Answer (score 1):

I think I was following the same tutorial as you.  :)  I abandoned the "st-flash" updater mentioned in the tutorial and used the one that's downloadable from the official STM site, called "STM32 ST-LINK utility" and used their CLI command that comes in the package.

I created a tasks.json in VSCode and used the following syntax (some funky syntax because I have spaces in my path) and have been able to start flashing my board.  Of course you probably want to add ST-LILNK_CLI.exe to your path but this is just a quick example of what worked for me before I started tidying things up.

```
"command": "&'M:/dev/stm32/STM32 ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK Utility/ST-LINK_CLI.exe' -ME -P ./build/free-rtos-test.bin 0x08000000 -V -HardRst"
```

FYI the HardRst parameter seems to fail unless it's at the very end.